# Why the FlexySlider slideshow is not loaded into this WordPress theme?

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am pretty new in WordPress theme developing and I have the following problem.

I am trying to create a WordPress theme that used BootStrap CSS framework based on this BootStrap demo static website (I have the entire source of this site because it is a downlodable tutorial): http://www.html.it/guide/img/bootstrap/demo/home.html

This is my custom WP theme: http://onofri.org/WP_BootStrap/

So I have create a basic WP theme and as first stage I want to insert the slideshow of the previous demo page in the header.php file of my WP theme, so this is my header.php code:

```
DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" <?php language_attributes(); ?>
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php bloginfo('html_type'); ?>; charset=<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" />
<title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> <?php if ( is_single() ) { ?> » Blog Archive <?php } ?> <?php wp_title(); ?></title>
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress <?php bloginfo('version'); ?>" />
<!-- leave this for stats -->

<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>" />

<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Sezione slider con Flexslider -->
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
     <div id="main-slider" class="flexslider">
      <ul class="slides">
       <li>
           <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/img/flexslider/flex-1.jpg"/>
           <div class="flex-caption">
               <p class="flex-caption-text">
                   <span>Lorem ipsum</span><br>
                   <span>sit dolor</span><br>
                   <span>adipiscing elitur</span>
               </p>
           </div>
       </li>
       <li>
           <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/img/flexslider/flex-2.jpg"/>
           <div class="flex-caption">
               <p class="flex-caption-text">
                   <span>Lorem ipsum</span><br>
                   <span>sit dolor</span><br>
                   <span>adipiscing elitur</span>
               </p>
           </div>
       </li>
       <li>
           <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/img/flexslider/flex-3.jpg"/>
           <div class="flex-caption">
               <p class="flex-caption-text">
                   <span>Lorem ipsum</span><br>
                   <span>sit dolor</span><br>
                   <span>adipiscing elitur</span>
           </p>
           </div>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </div><!-- /.flexslider -->
    </div><!-- /.col-sm-12 -->
    </div><!-- /.row -->

<center>
<div id="page">
<div id="header">

<h1><a href="<?php echo get_settings('home'); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a></h1>
<div class="description"><?php bloginfo('description'); ?></div>
</div>
<hr />
```

As you can see I have simply take the block of the static demo website and I have put it at the beginning of my header.php file.

To load my **jquery.flexslider.js** I use this code into WordPress **functions.php** file following the WordPress standard used to load JavaScripts:

```
/* Function automatically executed by the hook 'load_java_scripts':
 * 1) Load all my JavaScripts
 */
function load_java_scripts() {
    // Load JQuery:
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    // Load bootstrap.min.js:
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap.min-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), 'v3.0.3', true);
    // Load FlexSlider JavaScript
    wp_enqueue_script('flexSlider-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/plugins/flexslider/jquery.flexslider.js', array('jquery'), 'v2.1', true);
    // Load FancyBox:
    wp_enqueue_script('fancy-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/plugins/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js', array('jquery'), 'v2.1.5', true);
    // Load scripts.js:
    wp_enqueue_script('fancy-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/scripts.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_java_scripts');
```

As you can see the **jquery.flexslider.js** should be loaded into all my pages, infact (in FireFox) looking at the end of the page source there is:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/AsperTheme/assets/plugins/flexslider/jquery.flexslider.js?ver=v2.1'></script>
```

And clicking on it you can see the source of **jquery.flexslider.js**

Ok, my WordPress theme is configured to use the BootStrap CSS and the flexslider.css and also the style2.css file that represent what in the demo website is the stili-custom.css (my custom CSS settings that is loaded at last to ovverride the definied properties)

As you can see the problem is that at the beginning of my theme the slide show not appear and I have no idea about this issue.

Why? Can you help me to solve this problem?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 1):

I see you loading the flexslider js, but are you actually calling on flexslider to build your slideshow?

Something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.flexslider').flexslider({option1: value, option2: value});
});
```

Comment: mmm but why in the pure HTML demo website I have not this kind of call? I am refering to this demo site: http://www.html.it/guide/img/bootstrap/demo/home.html

Comment: If you go into developer tools and then scroll down to the bottom of the demo page you'll see a list of scripts being loaded. One of them is `scripts.js`in that file is the code calling on flexslider to create the slideshow (lines 3-9)

`$(window).load(function() {
 $('#main-slider').flexslider({
     animation: "slide",
     useCSS: false,
     pauseOnHover: true
 });
});`